# How to insert test code

Tags: haskell, testing

How can I add some testing code inside my functions?

e.g. I tried to change:

```
peuple i =
  let parcours = ...
```

by:

```
peuple i =
  do putStrLn $ "entering peuple " ++ i
  let parcours = ...
```

but I get a parse error.

EDIT

I tried with this code :

```
peuple :: Int -> Arbre
peuple 1 = Feuille
peuple i =
  do
    print ("entering peuple " ++ show i)
    ...
```

but ghc complains the method should return a "Arbre" and not an "IO" sth.

And more generally it is possible, e.g. in scala, to replace a code by a block {..;a} and in this case, the block will be evaluated as "a". Is it possible in Haskell?

Comment: can u show the error ?

Comment: I highly recommend starting with e.g. http://learnyouahaskell.com

Comment: yes, I know that putStrLn is of type string -> IO() and is hence not compatible with a return type "arbre"; but I' m wondering why the last expression in the code is not the only which matters for tyhe return value of a block of code. but maybe this information is also in the book you told me about... maybe I will have a look. thanks

Comment: Nobody has an answer ? The lack of an efficient graphical debugger should make people  turn to manually print values yet...

Comment: @lolveley For debugging purposes, you can use [`trace`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace) from the `Debug.Trace` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell is a pure language in the sense that functions in Haskell are referentially transparent. Look at the type of `peuple`:

```
peuple :: Int -> Arbre
```

A user (or other code) invoking this function should expect to give the function an `Int`, and get back an `Arbre`. We don't expect it to do anything else. Now what you seem to want is for an effect (or effects) to occur in this function: you want to print values to the console. Where in the type signature would you be able to tell that this function performs some sort of effect? You wouldn't. That's a no-no in Haskell.

Haskell allows us to perform effects as long as referential transparency is preserved. Printing something to the console will involve the use of the `IO` monad. But the `IO` monad is "one way": once you have an `IO a`, you can't just extract the `a` and ditch the `IO` container, so that the type of the function mentions nothing of the `IO` monad. If you could, then you'd have written a function that performs effects but doesn't let on that it does so. So you'll have to write a function that returns an `IO Arbre` if you want the function to represent a computation that returns an `Arbre`, but that performs some effects like printing to the console.

I second `mb21`'s suggestion to check out LYAH or another intro book that explains monads, and the `IO` monad in particular.

More to the point, referential transparency is the main reason that throwing `print ...` into your code is not an option in Haskell. If you want to debug code, you could use the GHCI debugger. If you want to test code, maybe use a tool like QuickCheck. Or look for other tools for debugging and testing code. But spending time learning about monads is the key here.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. I learned a bit of scala before and was hence confused, scala being very permissive for side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
peuple i =
  do putStrLn $ "entering peuple " ++ i
  let parcours = ...
```

should be

```
peuple i =
  do putStrLn $ "entering peuple " ++ i
     let parcours = ...
```

since indentation matters.